# Boost microphone input

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, audio-recording

I have a Shure SM58 microphone, so this is used with a pre-amp. Before I buy one, however, I was wondering if it is possible on a Windows 10 computer to boost the audio input levels. I know the volume level in Sound > Recording Devices > Line In > Properties. But is there a way to make it louder even more? Thanks!

Comment: If you find a way to boost that, you will probably overdrive the signal and cause distortion. Your preamp should allow you to boost to the maximum the line in levels will tolerate.

Comment: What Xavierjazz said. Your line in is only meant to drive up to a certian, relatively low voltage (computer mics). Past that, you're gonna need a pre-amp

Answer (score -1):

You can boost the microphone input, I am not sure if this was meant by your steps mentioned in the question: [Sound > Recording Devices > Line In > Properties], as this naming is slightly different, though this might be just a problem of translation of course. To be sure that there is no mistunderstanding, I post the steps in pictures.

[image]

Following picture:

You may limit the microphone to a certain volume level. This is good if you want to suppress exceptionally loud clicking noise when moving or touching the micro, I would even recommend to keep it rather at 50 % than at 100 % for that reason, but play around yourself, I am not a professional.

You see now a good 53 %, but this is already after the changes in the second next picture. Before adding 20 dB, it reached only 1-2 %. After some testing, the +20 dB seem to be quite exactly what was needed.

[image]

[image]

Summing up:
In my case, the amplification was needed since the microphone was too muted "by design". I could hold it directly in front of the mouth getting just 2 %, almost screaming gave me 6 %. The main volume or the microphone volume of the output (first and second picture) do not influence this, you need to change the input (third picture). If instead a microphone does not have this problem, and you use the digital amplifier of Windows 10, that might cause distortions. But I am also not sure about this: when I had added 20 dB, I did not notice any distortion at all. Please comment if you have other experiences.

Comment: Please remove your out of scope commentary from this answer.  You cannot ping users within an answer.  Those users are not going to reply to those pings.